# How to return the key from object value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, key-value

I have an object in React that I mapped and wanted to make it interact: I want it so when user clicks on the 'X' button next to an element, it would console.log the key of that clicked element.

Here is the object:

```
var obj = {
  person1: {
    name: 'iggy',
    superPower: 'awesomeness',
    favDonut: 'chocolate'
  },
  person2: {
    name: 'iggy2',
    superPower: 'stupendousness',
    favDonut: 'glazed'
  },
  person3: {
    name: 'iggy3',
    superPower: 'amazingness',
    favDonut: 'chocolate sprinkles'
  }
};
```

The iteration looks like this:

```
X chocolate
X glazed
X chocolate sprinkles
```

If I click the x on `glazed`, I want it to console.log `person2` because that's the parent object of `glazed`. If I click x on `chocolate sprinkles`, I want it to console.log `person3`.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iggyfiddle/b9rreoje/2/

The method that I am trying to figure out is the `getPersonName` function. What is the best way to allow user to click on the x and console.log the relevant object key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing `Object.values` you'll want to do `Object.keys`, so you can then access the corresponding key.

```
  getPersonName: function(person){
    console.log(person);
  }

const donutValues = Object.keys(obj).map((key, index) => <li key={index}><a href="#" onClick={() => this.getPersonName(key)}>X</a> {obj[key].favDonut} </li>);
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9rreoje/3/

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)... ` while displays `obj[key].favDonut`. Didn't think of that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `onClick` to an inline function that calls `getPersonName` with the corresponding person object.

```
  getPersonName: function(person){
    console.log(person);
  },

  render(){
    const donutValues = Object.values(obj).map((person, index) => <li key={index}><a href="#" onClick={function(){this.getPersonName(person)}.bind(this)}>X</a> {person.favDonut} </li>);
    return (
      <div>
        Hello 
          <ul>
            {donutValues}
          </ul>
          Give me person: {this.state.person}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Find the updated jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8637u8qL/